# How can i change the size limit of commit message on events page on gitlab

Tags: gitlab

[image]

hello all,

i tried to change this line
https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/a7f52b6cc25991bffa30eefa7d8bd6be138cffec/app/helpers/events_helper.rb#L173

but it didnt help me to view whole commit message.
How can i do that?

Thanks in advance..